# When I calculated the duration between 28/07/2018 and 01/08/2018, its result was two days. the correct answer is four days. what is my mistake?

Tags: c#, duration

When I calculated the ***duration*** between **28/07/2018** and **01/08/2018**, its result was two days. **the correct answer is four days**. what is my mistake?

my Code is :

```
  private static double DateDurationCalculate(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
            return span.TotalDays;
        }
```

startTime is **2018/07/28 11:54** and endTime is **2018/08/01 09:28**.

[image]

Comment: yes, it's four days.

Comment: When i use that method and pass in the given dates i get this result, `3,89861111111111`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnE53C

Comment: Are you sure that your dates parsed correctly?

Comment: It seems to work properly, can you put more code? Specially the part where you create the DateTime objects http://rextester.com/KWX56665

Comment: @BehrouzMoslem You might want to check the timespans in your question. You are talking about two different timespans and one seems completely off.

Comment: "When I calculated the duration between 28/07/2018 and 08/08/2018, its result was two days" - that end date looks very different to the value you've said later on. Please provide a [mcve]. I'd expect a return value of just less than 4, which is what Suppe showed.

Comment: why at the begin the `endTime` is `08/08/2018` then it turn into `2018/08/01`?

Comment: thanks .the correct date is 2018/08/01.  my question is edited

Comment: So, how you are creating dates that passed to your function? I suspect that problem is there and you actually have wrong dates.

Comment: Result was two days? Are you sure it wasn't -201 days?

Comment: Show the code that calls the function. As it stand the function works correctly.

Comment: hi Salman, yes I'm sure, it returns 2

Comment: hi TaW, by fixed parameter, the result is same. DateDurationCalculate(DateTime.Parse("2018/07/28 11:54"),DateTime.Parse("2018/08/01 09:28"))

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("2018/07/28 11:54");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("2018/08/01 09:28");    


private static double DateDurationCalculate(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    startTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, 0);
    endTime = new DateTime(endTime.Year, endTime.Month, endTime.Day, endTime.Hour, endTime.Minute, 0);
    TimeSpan span = endTime.Date.Subtract(startTime.Date);
    return span.TotalDays;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to (and it doesn't work) `@` notify the question asker if you post an answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, okay thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @BehrouzMoslem, please mention how will you pass the startTime and endTime to DateDurationCalculate().

Comment: @Achu_L DateDurationCalculate(DateTime.Parse("2018/07/28 11:54"),DateTime.Parse("2018/08/01 09:28"))

Comment: Calling the code in this answer using the call in your most recent comment yields `4`, not `2`. You either *haven't* copied the code from this question, or there are some other layers of code we know nothing about that mean you're seeing `2`.

Comment: @BehrouzMoslem, Copy and Paste my updated code. You get 4 (As per your screenshot I updated my code. please refer)

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to everyone**, my problem was solved with the following method.

```
   private static double DateDurationCalculate(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            var usCulture = "en-US";
            startTime = DateTime.Parse(startTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new CultureInfo(usCulture, true));
            endTime = DateTime.Parse(endTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new CultureInfo(usCulture, true));
            TimeSpan span = endTime.Date.Subtract(startTime);
            return span.TotalDays;
        }
```